# при задании одного и того же значения margin-right и margin-bottom вертикальные и горизонтальные отступы визуально разные

Tags: css, css3

```
.grid-container .game-field {
  width: 424px;
  min-width: 424px;
  max-width: 424px;
  height: 424px;
  max-height: 424px;
  min-height: 424px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 7px solid black;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.game-field .filled {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  padding: 4px 0 0 13px;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  border: none;
}
```

считаю так: (1 квадратик (90рх) + отступ слева (10рх) ) * 4 = 400рх 

+ еще отступ спава = 410рх 

+ рамка 7рх с двух сторон = 424рх

почему у меня маргины вертикальные и горизонтальные ну даже на глаз разные?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ставлю `margin: 0 6px 10px 0;` и все выравнивается[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

исходник: 

https://muturgan.github.io/barley-break/
https://github.com/muturgan/muturgan.github.io/tree/master/barley-break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы используете инлайн-блок. Инлайн-блок для браузера - это что-то вроде слова, и поэтому между ними(словами) есть промежутки, которые для вас лишние. Замените отображение на блоки с флоатами, флексбоксы или гриды, и тогда ваши лишние промежутки исчезнут.